# Navigation bar color not setting properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-color, navigationbar

Why is the navigation bar color coming so weired? Why is it white above and only a bit red at the bottom. I cannot make out if the status bar is overlapping my navigation bar or what. This is the code I used to change the color of the navigation bar background:

```
    [navbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you need to set bar tint color instead of background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

```
[navbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[navbar setTranslucent:NO];
```

**Why**

The color of a `UINavigationBar` is set with its [`barTintColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624931-bartintcolor) property.

What you're seeing is the translucent white navigation bar above your red background. The bit at the bottom is where `UINavigationBar` renders a shadow below the bar view.

Comment: by doing [navbar setTranslucent:NO], now the translucent nav bar has become completely white.

Answer (score 1):

I think this image is sufficient to solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: please suggest something else.